# How to remove instanceof for calling the correct method?

Tags: java

I have the following hierarchy of classes:

```
public interface Message
public interface V2Message extends Message
public interface V3Message extends Message
```

I defined another interface to validate a message.

```
public interface Validation {
  boolean validate(Message message);
}
```

Each class that implements `Validation` can deal with V2 and/or V3 messages, so in my implementation I have to distinguish the kind of message I want to validate because the code will be different.

```
public class MyValidation implements Validation {
  public boolean validate(Message message) {
    if(message instanceof V2Message) {
      return validateV2((V2Message)message);
    } else if (message instanceof V3Message) {
      return validateV3((V3Message)message);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to remove the use of `instanceof`.

Comment: Try reading this article by Steve Yegge:
http://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give `Validate` two methods rather than one:

```
public interface Validation {
  boolean validate(V2Message message);
  boolean validate(V3Message message);
}
```

That would also prevent passing in a simple `Message` being a runtime error. This is also a more accurate API, since you've said that `Validation` implementations can't deal with `Message`, only `V2Message` and `V3Message`.

Comment: So if `MyValidation` does not handle V3 messages, I guess the implementation of the second method will be empty.

Comment: @Sydney: If you want to be able to have classes that can only validate one or the other, then you want two different interfaces: `V2Validation` containing `validate(V2Message)` and, separately, `V3Validation` containing `validate(V3Message)`. A class that can handle both can implement both. It's generally a bad idea to have a class say it can do something it can't do. (Sadly, it's sometimes necessary to avoid an explosion of tiny classes and interfaces, but avoid it if you possibly can.)

Answer (score 5):

One way is to implement the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Define a MessageVisitor interface:

```
public interface MessageVisitor {
  boolean visit(V2Message message);
  boolean visit(V3Message message);
}
```

Then redefine the Message interface to include a method:

```
public void visitMessage(MessageVisitor visitor);
```

Each concrete class of Message would then implement the `visitMessage` method something like this:

```
public void visitMessage(MessageVisitor visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
}
```

Since this is defined in each concrete subclass, the compiler will invoke the correct version of `visit`.

This may be overkill if all you need is validation. But if you are going to be implementing other operations that need to work on different kinds of messages differently, it has the advantage that you can implement each of them without changing the message classes at all. The pros and cons are described in the article link at the start of this post.

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface Message{
   boolean validate();
}
```

Your concrete classes that implement `Message` will then be responsible for knowing what do when they're asked to `validate()`.

Comment: This has the tradeoff of forcing the `Message` implementation to implement validation logic when arguably that concern should be separated out as the OP originally had.

Comment: @KirkWoll Agreed on your point about separation, especially in what context I'm imagining the OP's code. However my aim was to answer the question "... a way to remove the use of instanceof".

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me as rather tight binding to require knowledge about the internal workings of a class/interface to be able to "validate" it. If possible, you should make the `Message` interface have its own validation.

That would yield something like this:

```
public interface Message{
   boolean validate();
   // Stüfe
}
```

But, it could be that there is something fundamentally different between how it is validated. (Similar has been known to happen in the observer pattern). In such a case, I would likely use overloading to differentiate.

```
public interface Validation {
  boolean validate(V2Message message);
  boolean validate(V3Message message);
  boolean validate(Message message); // may not be needed, but in case you want 
                                     // still handle generic Messages, you will
                                     // definitely need it.
  // Stüfe
}
```

As stated above, that could give you the benefit of more compile-time errors. It will not provide any substantial feedback in addition to what you are already getting though — your code will cause the same error as passing a generic `Message`.

Comment: Doesn't this just duplicate the existing answers?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, in all fairness, I started writing this before they were posted. But even if I hadn't, this combines the two and adds information.